# Set up virtual host on apache to allow Zend on same domain as another application / static website

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, redirect, virtualhost

The goal is to set up a Zend application on the same domain as a static website efficiently. Currently the following is true but slow:

- www.website.com/ redirects to www.website.com/corp/index.html
- /admin, /login, /session resolved to /index.php where the zend application resides

I have set up redirects to www.website.com/corp/index.html in my bootstrap file, but no matter what page I visit this redirect has to occur when appropriate. It is slowing down the entire static site. Here is my virtual host httpd.conf entry which is redirecting everything to /index.php but I want to place an exception that allows access to /corp without the redirects once you are in that directory. Other simple and effective solutions are certainly welcome as well.

```
<VirtualHost *:18887>
   DocumentRoot c:\pathtoapp\public
   ServerName website.com

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "local"
     <Directory c:\pathtoapp\public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify Zend Framework's `.htaccess` file to bypass sending anything requests to `/corp/*` to the front controller, you should be able to bypass this issue.

Try changing your `.htaccess` file in your public directory to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^corp\/* [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The first RewriteCond checks to see if the request filename matches `/corp/*` and if it does, bypasses the front controller and serves the request directly through Apache and your Zend Application never has to handle any of these requests.

Comment: After testing this fully I could not get this to work properly. A guess is that when files are 404 outside the corp directory (accidental) then those requests are taking down the page. Is there a way to exclude img xml files etc?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what do you mean "those requests are taking down the page", and what part of it isn't fully working?  I guess it is partial though?

Comment: Sorry your response was perfect, there was another issue causing a redirect. Thanks!